# cannot initialize a parameter of type with an lvalue of in latest xcode throws an error

Tags: xcode, macos, delegates

I have a following line of code in xcode - using objective c

```
[m_port setDelegate:self];
```

it throws an compilation error in latest xcode say 5.x onwards where as in xcode 3.x this is able to compile perfectly.

`Error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSPortDelegate'` with an lvalue of 'AppMainController *'

Can someone explain me what is this error and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough information to answer this question completely, but it seems that the class `AppMainController` has not been declared to conform to protocol `NSPortDelegate`, like this:

```
@interface AppMainController : NSObject<NSApplicationDelegate, NSPortDelegate>
```

(I have assumed this is an OSX application as tags are missing from the question).

Comment: This works for me. it  is just a compilation error as i'm new to xcode i don't know it